# Receiving data causes "too many files open"

Tags: java, android, networking, zeromq

In my client I receive via ZeroMQ a lot of input, which needs to be constantly updated. My server is written in python, but that should not matter. So this is what I do in my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /********************************NETWORK********************************/
        new NetworkCall().execute("");
    }

    private class NetworkCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

                    // Connect to server
                    ZMQ.Socket requester = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
                    String address = "tcp://xxx.xx.xx.xx";
                    int port = 5000;
                    requester.connect(address + ":" + port);

                    // Initialize poll set
                    ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(1);
                    poller.register(requester, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);

                    requester.send("COORDINATES");

                    //while (true) {
                    String data;
                    poller.poll();

                    data = requester.recvStr();
                    System.out.println(data);

                    if (data == null) {
                        try {
                            sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } requester.close();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                    ise.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

After executing this code on my device, I'll get like 5-9 input data strings, which I receive from the server, but then the following exception appears:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                  Process: com.example.viktoria.gazefocus, PID: 31339
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Caused by: com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.ZError$IOException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Signaler.makeFdPair(Signaler.java:94)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Signaler.<init>(Signaler.java:50)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Mailbox.<init>(Mailbox.java:51)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Ctx.<init>(Ctx.java:128)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.ZMQ.zmq_ctx_new(ZMQ.java:244)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.ZMQ.zmqInit(ZMQ.java:277)
                      at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.<init>(ZMQ.java:269)
                      at org.zeromq.ZMQ.context(ZMQ.java:254)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.MainActivity$NetworkCall.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:73)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.MainActivity$NetworkCall.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
                      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
                      at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:42)
                      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
                      at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Signaler.makeFdPair(Signaler.java:91)
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Signaler.<init>(Signaler.java:50) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Mailbox.<init>(Mailbox.java:51) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.Ctx.<init>(Ctx.java:128) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.ZMQ.zmq_ctx_new(ZMQ.java:244) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.zmq.ZMQ.zmqInit(ZMQ.java:277) 
                      at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.<init>(ZMQ.java:269) 
                      at org.zeromq.ZMQ.context(ZMQ.java:254) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.MainActivity$NetworkCall.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:73) 
                      at com.example.viktoria.gazefocus.MainActivity$NetworkCall.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67) 
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Apparently too many files are open. After research (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04) I changed the `ulimit` with `ulimit -n 10000`. Still this exception will happen. Sometimes I get more input data, sometimes less. Also if I set something like `Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` into the `onCreate()` method, nothing will change.

How to overcome this issue?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leak because you're not closing / ending / freeing something. I *think* that the context has to be terminated: `context.term()` after you close the requester...

Comment: It's always those obvious things... Cheers!

Comment: Negative, Sir, a call to the **`.term()`***-method after all will not save the game, as the infinite `while( true ){...}`-looping generates new `Context()`-instance each and every loop and never dismantled any resources used during the previous pass, neither during a next round-trip nor during an exception handling. This will not fly.

Comment: @ user3666197 - trust me, it'll fly when you term the context on every iteration in the loop. Same number of contexts made, some number terminated, balance 0, no leak, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) design, the infrastructure for signalling / messaging setup costs are not negligible. Some use-cases are more foregiving, some less.

Getting always a new **`Context()`** instance per each method-call and throwing it right away soon after by a clean-up call to it's **`.term()`***-method is for sure better than having a hung-app or a frozen device, yet it is far from a fair design, respecting the process latencies and an "ecology"-of-resources.

Better first setup a semi-persistent infrastructure of resources ( each `Context()`-instance is typically a very expensive toy to instantiate ( API 4.2+ as of 2018-Q1 ), not so sharp for the `Socket()`-instances, but similar to the `Poller()` and all it's internal-AccessPoint(s) registration-hooks, yet the principle may extend on 'em too ).

Early re-factoring of the code will help not to extend the case with using expensive resources as a "consumable disposable".

The section:

```
      while (true) {
             try {
                    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

                    //                     Connect to server
                    ZMQ.Socket requester = context.socket( ZMQ.REQ );
                    String address = "tcp://xxx.xx.xx.xx";
                    int port = 5000;
                    requester.connect( address + ":" + port );
                    ...
             }
             ...
      }
```

is exactly a resources-devastating anti-pattern, altogether with repetitive latencies and even risks of remote-hangups and remote-rejections and similar issues.